# SwiftUI changing view based on variable, which resets in change of local variable's

Tags: swift, swiftui, model

On the profileView I have button which changes the view to the SettingsView. Which works through a model with I give through an environmentObject. When I'm on the settingsPage(second view) and I change a local variable in that view the profileView goes back to display. So the payload seems to reset when changing a local variable.

ProfileView()

```
struct ProfileView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var authentication: AuthenticationModel
    @ObservedObject var profile: ProfileModel = ProfileModel()
    
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            switch profile.profileView {
            case .settings:
                SettingsView()
                    .environmentObject(profile)
                    .environmentObject(authentication)
                    .transition(.backslide)
            case .profile:
            etc...
```

ProfileModel:

```
import Foundation

class ProfileModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var profileView: ProfileView = .profile
    
    enum ProfileView {
        case profile, settings
    }

}
```

The SettingsView:

When I Click on the button to change DarkMode the payload of the model seems te reset. Resulting in going back to the profileView.

```
import SwiftUI

//View
struct SettingsView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var authentication: AuthenticationModel
    @EnvironmentObject var profile: ProfileModel
    
    //Darkmode
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) private var currentColorScheme
    @AppStorage("DarkMode") var isDarkMode: Bool = false

    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    
                    //MARK: - Header
                    HStack {
                        Button {
                            profile.profileView = .profile
                        } label: {
                            Image(systemName: "chevron.left")
                                
                        }
                        Spacer()
                        
                    } //header
                    
                    ScrollView {
                        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                
                                //MARK: - Dark mode
                                Button {
                                    isDarkMode.toggle() <-- Click results in reset of payload?
                                    
                                } label: {
                                   etc.
```

I tried it with IF statements, ENUM(switch) one model instead of 2. But it all results in the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line in ProfileView

```
@ObservedObject var profile: ProfileModel = ProfileModel()
```

To

```
@StateObject var profile: ProfileModel = ProfileModel()
```

When an object is created and needs persistence, we need to create it as a **StateObject** at its point of creation. Everywhere else where it is referred, it has to be either **ObservedObject**, or **EnvironmentObject**. Without it being a StateObject somewhere, SwiftUI will not keep its state and will create a new instance every time the view reloads.